Postfix client submission using TLS
I recently set up a Postfix mail server on Ubuntu to relay emails from my apps to Office365. Postfix to O365 works without problem but I also want my apps to connect to Postfix using TLS where possible.
I enabled port 465 under master.cf and added the following to my main.cf file:
# Server to Server
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer=yes
smtp_tls_loglevel = 2
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private.key
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/relay_cert.cer
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/inter_cert.cer

relayhost = [domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com]:25


# Client to Server
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/relay_cert.cer
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/inter_cert.cer
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

But when I try to send a test mail using SSL I get:

Send-MailMessage : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

In the Postfix logs, I don't get anything that would help:

lost connection after STARTTLS from server.domain.local[192.168.1.1]

The cert and intermediate cert seem fine, they work for the O365 communication, so I don't know what's going wrong.
Edit: connecting locally with openssl I was able to relay using ESMTPS, so possibly it's an issue with my Windows server.
openssl s_client -connect mailserver.domain.local:465 -starttls smtp


Why does the validation procedure find the remote certificate invalid?

That's what I'm trying to find out but increased logging on both sides doesn't give me anything other than what's written in my question.

Finally worked out that it was just PowerShell being fussy about the SMTP server not matching the certificate.
So this won't work

Send-MailMessage -To user@gmail.com -from  relay@domain.com -Subject
'test'  -SmtpServer server.mydomain.local -UseSsl -Port 465

but this will:

Send-MailMessage -To user@gmail.com -from  relay@domain.com -Subject
'test'  -SmtpServer relay.domain.com -UseSsl -Port 465

Other apps don't seem to be as particular as PowerShell.

What if any "other apps" besides openssl commandline? That doesn't verify name in server cert by default; you need to specify an option per the man page. But RFC 3207 4.1 says an SMTP client "would probably want" the correct domain name.

Tree Size Pro to name the first app I tried. If an app doesn't bother with client submission on port 587 they probably aren't too bothered about RFCs either.
